# LOAM Package needed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Dear Robotists!

Can any one send LOAM package to me, bcz its no more available on ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/loam_velodyne ).
my email:  snulove@yahoo.com ;  milyasmeo@gmail.com

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269694/loam-package-needed/) by [milyasmeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31720/milyasmeo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-28**:
What are you planning to do with it? There are separate branches for different Velodyne models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to ask the author (Ji Zhang) why he removed the repository from his account.

In any case: a search on GitHub revealed that [daobilige-su/loam_velodyne](https://github.com/daobilige-su/loam_velodyne) is apparently a fork of a fork of Ji Zhang's repository:

> This is a LOAM (Lidar Odometry and Mapping) ROS package for Velodyne VLP-16 3D laser scanner. This package is a simple modified copy of loam_velodyne git repository from laboshinl, which is again a modified copy of the original one release by Ji Zhang.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-28**:
He removed it because he started a company with it (http://www.kaarta.com/).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-28**:
That's unfortunate then.

It does appear that the code was originally already BSD licensed, so no problem in continuing to use the forks then.

But @milyasmeo: the licensing aspect would be something for you to check.